# PHP Tables with Pagination bootstrap

Tags: php, pagination, html-table

I am getting from the database data in a PHP table bootstrap. What I want is to do the pagination now, because the table I get is to long, and I want to have for example 6 rows/page. This is my code with DataTables Plugin but it's not working :/ Can anyone help me?

```
 <html>
 <!-- DataTables CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"           href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 
 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script >
 <!-- DataTables -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"       src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 

<div class="container">
<div class="row vertical-center-row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="table-responsive">
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
            <table id="table" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <h3>Update/Remove Access Rights</h3>
            <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Nickname</th>
    <th> Door Description </th>

  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').dataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} );
} );
 </script>
  <?php 
    $stmt="select id_access_rights,name,surname,nickname, description 
           from users
           join access_rights on users.rfidcode=access_rights.users_rfidcode
           join doors 
           on doors.id_doors=access_rights.doors_id_doors
           order by name ";

    $result=$conn->query($stmt);
    if($result === FALSE) { 
  die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
 }
                while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){

                    $f1=$row['id_access_rights'];
                    $f2=$row['name'];
                    $f3=$row['surname'];
                    $f4=$row['nickname'];
                    $f5=$row['description'];
                    ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $f1 ?>
<td><?php echo $f2 ?>
<td><?php echo $f3 ?>
<td><?php echo $f4 ?>
<td><?php echo $f5 ?>
<td><?php echo "<a href='updateAccessRights.php?id_access_rights=" . htmlentities($f1). "'>Update";?>
<td><?php echo "<a href='deleteAccessRights.php?id_access_rights=" . htmlentities($f1). "'>Remove";?>
</td>
<?php 
}
?>  
</tr>
</table>
</tbody>
</table>
            <br>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typically for pagination using just PHP, I would add a "limit" to the query that chooses a starting point and a limit to how many results. If the limit is 5, you should have two variables. page ($_GET['page']) and limit ($limit). To get the starting point, use (($_GET['page'] - 1) * $limit). Use these variables in your query.

Comment: How can I add them into the query only just two variables ?

Comment: It says Undefined Variable page

Comment: Add "limit $offset, $limit" to the query if $offset = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $limit

Comment: In this case what kind of value become $limit ? In your question it's not defined. And also what about variable page ?

Comment: $limit would be how many results you'd like to show per page. Keep in mind, I'm just throwing basic pagination at you, not directly answering how to do it with the DataTables plugin, hence why I'm commenting and not answering.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't work $_GET['page'] ,it says not defined. Also a question, how can I set down the page the number of pages, so i can get also into another pages

Comment: I would put something like if (!isset($_GET['page']): $_GET['page'] = 1;

To switch pages, link to the url of that page but append "?page=<?= $_GET['page']++ ?>" to go to the next page.

Comment: Do you any code that's work?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Data Tables

- Javascript Code

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable();
  } );
  In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js

HTML Code

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS Code -

```
body { font-size: 140%; }
```

The following CSS library files are loaded for use in this example to provide the styling of the table:

//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

Please refer this for further details -
[https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html](http://Data%20Tables)

Comment: I did all of these things, also referred to this page http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html  but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use datatables, javascript plugin.
https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Include it's css on the top of your page, and js after your jquery. and then call $('table').DataTable();

Comment: I am new on bootstrap,jQueries and DataTables. Can you please do the necessary changes on my code